# Jquery Slidetoggle multiple sliding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have been browsing for a fair while and I am still to find a relevant answer. I am wanting my hidden divs that are all the same class to slidetoggle, but when one slides the other that is open closes. Also I am wanting the Show Information/Hide information only to change for the div that is being toggled.

Here is my html

```
<p>
    <a class="opener" href="javascript:slideTogle();">Click Here For Information</a>
</p>
<div class="content">
    <p>If you are looking to purchase your first home, reduce your existing monthly
        repayments, pay off you mortgage early, raise cash for home improvements
        or to pay off debt or even buy a property to let out we are able to assist
        and advise you from start to finish. We have access to a wide range of
        lenders offering independent mortgages to suit you.</p>
    <p>Your home may be repossessed if you do not keep up repayments on your
        mortgage.</p>
    <ul>
        <li>First time Buyers</li>
        <li>Remortgages</li>
        <li>Capital raising</li>
        <li>Debt Consolidation</li>
        <li>Buy To Let</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content.open').show();

    $('.opener').click(function () {


        $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle(300, function () {
            $(".opener").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Hide Information" : "Click Here For Information");
        });
    });
});
```

I am new to jquery/javascript but I have a basic knowledge of php and a good knowledge of html/css.

thanks

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
   var showText='Click for more Information &#9658';
   var hideText='Hide Information &#9660';
 $('.content.open').show();
 $('.opener').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().next('.content').slideToggle('slow');
 // switch visibility
 $(this).data('is_visible', !$(this).data('is_visible'));
 // change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
 $(this).html( (!$(this).data('is_visible')) ? showText : hideText);
 $('.parent, .child').hide();
 });});

Answer (score 0):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n2GLj/11/)?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.

    $('.opener').click(function (e) {
        var $opener = $(this);
        var $content = $opener.parent().next('.content');        

        e.preventDefault();

        $content.toggleClass('open').slideToggle(300, function(){
            $opener.text($content.hasClass('open')?"Hide Information":"Click Here For Information");
        });

    });
});​
```

Comment: I pasted my newest code in the comment below, the problem now is as I have multiple div's, closing one when opening the selected

Comment: I've changed the code so that all accordions would operate independently from each other.

Comment: It doesn't open the div's at all using this code. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry, could you maybe maybe edit your question to clarify what you are looking for? What we need to know is 1) what is on the page 2) how you interact with it 3) what the desired outcome is.